# Running value-counts() on column of generators in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a column of film genres in my Pandas data frame like so:

```
train['genre_names'] = train['genres'].map(lambda x: [dictionary['name'] for dictionary in x])

train['genre_names'] = train['genre_names'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Additional changes were made by the following code:

```
# By https://github.com/danbochman/Fatality-Analysis-Reporting-System

cols = ["genre_names"]
train_rev = train_rev.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.map(x.value_counts())< threshold, 'Other') if x.name in cols else x)
```

There are quite a few genres, so I wanted to run value_counts() on the column (`train['genre_names'].value_counts()`). It returned single counts of 3000 generator objects (the length of the column), instead of counts of the genres that appear as strings in the data frame.

I tried converting all column cells to strings and then running `value_counts()`, but I succeeded only in creating string generator objects.

```
generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr>
```

How can I get something like:

```
Horror 200
Drama 500
RomCom 700
Comic Book Films 5,000,000
```

Comment: Probably you want `train.groupby('genre_names').count()`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I'm going. I'm just bewildered as to how a generator got there. I'll look thru the docs. Wish there were a convenient way to transform them quickly into a specific data type that suits one's purposes.

Comment: Can you provide example of `train` as `train['genre_names'] = train['genre_names'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))` really confuses me. I am under the impression that you should not do so.